# How to disable individual TLS Extensions client side on Windows and Mac?

Tags: tls, macos, windows-10

I am trying to test different TLS 1.2/1.3 extensions support by turning them on and off on client side. I failed to find any way to do that in chrome://flags (or any other browser).

Is there a way to do it system-wide by changing settings in the OS?

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a way to do it system-wide by changing settings in the OS?

Different applications use different TLS stacks, which don't adhere to a single system wide policy. Even applications which use the Windows default TLS stack [Schannel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/security/tls/tls-ssl-schannel-ssp-overview) might use the system defaults only as a starting point but add their own configuration on top of it.

Apart from that the intention for system wide or application specific settings is usually to make things work, i.e. its about changing settings needed for compatibility with the communication peer. It is not about providing support for arbitrary tests like you are trying to do. For this one likely needs to write own programs to get deeper access to the features of a specific TLS stack or in some cases also write own TLS stacks since the API of the existing stacks does not offer any possible kind of handshake variation either.